# PHPMailer goes to spam

Tags: phpmailer

I have problem with PHPMailer. Messages go to spam on o2 and Hotmail. On other servers it works well. Here is my code:

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php'); 
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->From = "abc@mydomain.pl";
$mail->FromName = "XYZ";
$mail->AddReplyTo('abc@mydomain.pl', 'XYZ');
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = "mail.mydomain.pl"; 
$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "abc@mydomain.pl"; 
$mail->Password = "password"; 
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$mail->Body = "Message";
$mail->AddAddress ('xxx@yyy.pl','User');
$mail->Send();
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Delivery problems are all to do with DNS, SPF, DKIM, from address and prior sending reputation, not anything directly related to PHPMailer. You're also using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an old example; update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the possibility that your server may be blacklisted for some reason, the most common cause for emails landing in spam servers that i encountered is that the from-address and the server's name do not match.

Consider a from-address like `someone@mydomain.com` sent from a server `cheapwebhosting.com`, the recipient mail server sees the discrepancy and will most likely consider this a spam message.

So, you should check the message headers of a test email if something like this is happening here (or if you notice anything else that looks fishy)